# Использовать ли одну и ту же POJO модель и для получение ответов с сервера и для ORM?

Tags: android, android-room, pojo

Для Retrofita я создал следующую POJO модель с помощью генератора с сайта:
[image: POJO для ретрофита]

Как видите получилось много классов. Дальше мне надо взаимодействовать с полученными данными в приложении и записать полученные данные в базу с помощью ORM Room.

Для Room мне необходимо будет указать с помощью аннотаций столбцы и таблицы. Соответственно данная модель не подходит для Room.

Так же мне надо будет взаимодействовать с моделью в приложении. Для этого мне можно использовать модель из Room или сделать еще одну?

и если создавать несколько моделей для одних и тех же данных, но более удобных для взаимодействия. То как организовать конвертацию одной модели в другую?

Comment: Список ни о чем не говорит сам по себе. Возьмите один класс и сделайте Room Entity для него. Станет понятно, получится их обьединить или нет. Если не станет, спрашивайте уже конкретно.

Comment: Если вы используете связи в таблице и ваши **POJO** имеют связи, то это будет трудно сделать в рамках **Room**. 
Если же вы готовы хранить каждое **POJO** без связей, то это вполне возможно, написав свои `TypeConvertors`

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja
Суть в том, что там данные простые город и погода. Мне бы удобней было использовать один класс в котором были бы эти данные, как я понял можео создать для каждого источника данных свою модель, а так же модель для удобного взаимодействия в программе. Но мне интересно как организовать конвертацию моделей, мне кто сказал, что для этого подойдут маперы.

Comment: @pavel163 я написал комментарий выше.